# Nested list in multicolumn, problem with resume

Tags: lists, enumerate, multicol, enumitem

### Background

I have to copy some questions from a paper to LaTeX. However I don't have the source code for the work so I've got to it by hand.

So far, I've used a couple of enumerate environments with a multicols inside. The output doesn't look like the source and I'm having trouble figuring out why is that so.

### My code

```
\begin{enumerate}[label=\Roman*.]
  \item Utilice la definición de transformada para evaluar $L\set{f(t)}$
  \begin{multicols}{2}
        \begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*.]
          \item q1
          \item 12
          \item graf1
          \item graf2
        \end{enumerate}
  \end{multicols}
  \item Utilice las tablas para evaluar $L\set{f(t)}$.
         \begin{multicols}{2}
        \begin{enumerate}[resume,label=\arabic*.]
          \item $f(t)=(1+e^{-2t})^2$
          \item $f(t)=3t^2-4\cosh(2t)$
          \item $f(t)=\sin(t)\.\cos(2t)$
          \item $f(t)=\cos(t)\.\cos(3t)$
        \end{enumerate}
  \end{multicols}
\end{enumerate}
```

### The problem

The code above produces this output

[MyOutput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ygwfy.jpg)

However, it should look like this

[OriginalWork](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2xcT.jpg)

*EDIT1:* This is my first question including an image and I couldn't get it to look like on most questions here. So I embedded it on HTML, if it's not an inconvenience I'd also ask help with this for future questions.

So far I've got two problems:

1. The list doesn't resume on the next item even if I'm using the resume after the enumerate environment. When I removed the multicols it did work and it did continue the list as it should've.
2. The enumeration on the correct work is row-wise, however on my output it's column-wise.

And my questions are:

1. Is there a way to nest lists even while using multicols? Can you show me how to do it? Or is there a better way to solve my problem without including multicols?
2. How can I transpose the order of enumeration? Is enumerate the right package to use here?

Any help is greatly appreciated! Kind regards.

Comment: http://ctan.imsc.res.in/macros/latex/contrib/exam/examdoc.pdf

Comment: https://www.overleaf.com/project/52e3f06d3cf27e7a050000ee

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. The tasks package will do what you want, both for resuming the numbering and for arranging the lists row-wise.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a suggestion using the packages `xsim` and `tasks`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xsim}
\usepackage{tasks}

\DeclareExerciseEnvironmentTemplate{minimal}
  {\par\noindent\textbf{\GetExerciseProperty{counter}} }
  {}

\xsimsetup{
  exercise/template = minimal ,
  exercise/the-counter = \Roman{exercise}.
}

\RenewTasksEnvironment[label=\arabic*.]{tasks}(2)

\DeclarePairedDelimiter\set{\{}{\}}

\begin{document}

\begin{exercise}
  Utilice la definición de transformada para evaluar $L\set{f(t)}$
  \begin{tasks}
    \task q1
    \task 12
    \task graf1
    \task graf2
  \end{tasks}
\end{exercise}
\begin{exercise}
  Utilice las tablas para evaluar $L\set{f(t)}$.
  \begin{tasks}[resume]
    \task $f(t)=(1+e^{-2t})^2$
    \task $f(t)=3t^2-4\cosh(2t)$
    \task $f(t)=\sin(t)\cos(2t)$
    \task $f(t)=\cos(t)\cos(3t)$
  \end{tasks}
\end{exercise}

\end{document}
```

[image]